# How to plot pandas.crosstab() columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot in the same figure the first *n* values which are the results of `pd.crosstab()`, I have tried:

```
tab = pd.crosstab(df['genre_ids'], df['target'],margins=True).sort_values('All',ascending=False)
tab = tab.drop('All',axis=1)
tab = tab.drop('All',axis=0)
tab[:top_n].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

but I get a *barplot* that doesn't rappresent the actual values present in the *tab*'s columns.

**EDIT:**

This is the *crosstab*:
[image]
I would like plot the values in columns *0* and *1*, but I get this plot that it's different from the values in the columns:
[image]
Is it possible get something like this:[image]
but with the *0* and *1* values plot in the same bar for each x-value?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] of the issue. Use some random or hardcoded values in the code and best also show an image of the output which lets you explain what's wrong with the plot.

Comment: The plot is correct. I guess the above comment applies even more now.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have updated the image now. The values in the plot seem incorrect.  At example: first x-value (341)  has a similar value for columns 0 and 1, but it's not represented in the plot.

Comment: Blue represents column 0. For ID 341 you have 1.7 million in that column, hence the blue bar goes from 0 to 1.7 million. Green represents column 1, you have a value of 1.8 million. Hence the green bar goes from 1.7 million, where the blue bar ends to 3.5 million (as 3.5 minus 1.7 is 1.8, this is correct as well). Really not clear what your problem is.

Comment: @Simone The values are indeed similar. Maybe you don't want to use stacking: `stacked = False`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved simply set `stacked = False` as has suggested @Nipun Batra in the comments.